# Partial template specialization of non type argument not allowed

Tags: c++, templates, metaprogramming, template-meta-programming

The following code does not work, it gives an error saying "Too few template arguments for struct foo" and I do not understand why. To me it seems like the code should be valid. I found a snippet from CPP reference [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/partial_specialization) in the section "The argument list", paragraph 4 which might explain why it does not work but I don't understand it.

```
template<int a, int b, int c> struct foo { };
template<int a> struct foo<a, 0, 0> { };

int main()
{
    foo<1> f;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not how template specialization works. You have* to specify all arguments.
<sub>*(Except when you have *default arguments* (see @StoryTeller's answer), or when C++17 argument deduction kicks in, but both don't apply here.)</sub>

Here's a small demo:

```
#include <iostream>

template<int a, int b, int c> struct foo { void bar() {std::cout << "1\n";} };
template<int a> struct foo<a, 0, 0> { void bar() {std::cout << "2\n";} };

int main()
{
    foo<1, 2, 3> a;
    foo<4, 0, 0> b;
    a.bar(); // prints 1
    b.bar(); // prints 2
}
```

Answer (score 4):

It's allowed. But your template takes 3 parameters. Specializing it doesn't magically turn it into a 1 parameter template.

You can make the other parameter have default arguments, however:

```
template<int a, int b = 0, int c = 0> struct foo { char _[1] ; };
template<int a> struct foo<a, 0, 0> { char _[10] ;};

int main() {
    static_assert(sizeof(foo<1>) > sizeof(foo<1, 1, 1>), "");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Isn't the idea of the specialization that I can now call it like foo<1> instead of foo<1, 0, 0> ?

Comment: @BananyaDev - No. Specialization is about controlling behavior for a specific set of parameters. It doesn't change how many parameters you need to pass.

Comment: @BananyaDev - There is however the ability to add default arguments for the parameters.

Answer (score 1):

Note that the primary template takes 3 template parameters. Then you have to specify all of them. e.g.

```
foo<1, 0, 0> f; // the partial specification is used
```